# How to select all options in multiselect Kendo UI dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

There is a MultiSelect DropDown from kendo ui mvc, I would like to have a select all option that when you click on that, all the options will be selected.
Here's my code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
        .HeaderTemplate("<label><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"selectAll\"> select all </label>")
        .Name("schoolNames")
        .Filter("Contains")
        .HtmlAttributes(new {style = "width: 100%;"})
        .DataTextField("title")
        .DataValueField("id")
        .AutoClose(false)
        .Events(e => e.Change("selectAllChange"))
        .DataSource(source =>
        {
            source.Read(read =>
            {
                read.Url( "/api/v1/Moodle/names/");
            })
                .ServerFiltering(false);
        })
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('#selectAll').on('click', () => {
    let multiSelect = $("#schoolNames").data("kendoMultiSelect");
    multiSelect.value(multiSelect.dataSource.data().toJSON().map(x => x.value));
});
```

Demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/index">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.616/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.616/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.616/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    
    

</head>
<body>
    <div id="example" role="application">
    <div class="demo-section k-content">
        <h2>Invite Attendees</h2>
        <label for="required">Required</label> 
        <button id='selectAll' type='button'>Select all</button>
        <select id="required" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select attendees...">
            <option>Steven White</option>
            <option>Nancy King</option>
            <option>Nancy Davolio</option>
            <option>Robert Davolio</option>
            <option>Michael Leverling</option>
            <option>Andrew Callahan</option>
            <option>Michael Suyama</option>
            <option>Anne King</option>
            <option>Laura Peacock</option>
            <option>Robert Fuller</option>
            <option>Janet White</option>
            <option>Nancy Leverling</option>
            <option>Robert Buchanan</option>
            <option>Margaret Buchanan</option>
            <option>Andrew Fuller</option>
            <option>Anne Davolio</option>
            <option>Andrew Suyama</option>
            <option>Nige Buchanan</option>
            <option>Laura Fuller</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <style>
        .demo-section label {
            display: block;
            margin: 15px 0 5px 0;
        }
        #get {
            float: right;
            margin: 25px auto 0;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // create MultiSelect from select HTML element
            var required = $("#required").kendoMultiSelect().data("kendoMultiSelect");
            $("#get").click(function() {
                alert("Attendees:\n\nRequired: " + required.value() + "\nOptional: " + optional.value());
            });
          
          $('#selectAll').on('click', () => {
            let multiSelect = $("#required").data("kendoMultiSelect");
            multiSelect.value(multiSelect.dataSource.data().toJSON().map(x => x.value));
          });
        });
    </script>
</div>


    

</body>
</html>
```

[Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/IRAFEval)